# multiple savefig() 's with different styles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a program, which has two outputs: a GUI and a printed report on paper (a simple pdf printed out).
On both outputs I would like to have a diagram, but with different styles.

- dark_background on the GUI (http://matplotlib.org/examples/style_sheets/plot_dark_background.html)
- and fivethirtyeight on the paper  http://matplotlib.org/examples/style_sheets/plot_fivethirtyeight.html

Somehow I could not manage to generate 2 images with proper styles. Only one of them was correct. I do not have enough experience-points to post pictures. So I will post only my code.

My first idea was:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot():
        #set pic size
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=100)
        ax = plt.subplot(111)
        # set x data
        x = range(10)
        # set y data
        y1 = np.zeros(10)
        y2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        y3 = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
        #plot as errorbar
        ax.errorbar(x, y1, fmt='o', color='green', markersize=8, label='Normal')
        ax.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=0.1, fmt='o', color='orange', markersize=8, label='abw_up')
        ax.errorbar(x, y3, yerr=0.1, fmt='o', color='purple', markersize=8,label='abw_down')
        # limits
        ax.axhline(0.1*10, color='red', lw=2)
        ax.axhline(-0.1*10, color='red', lw=2)
        #set limit of y-Axis
        ax.set_ylim((-1.3,1.3))
        # Labels
        ax.set_xlabel('points number')
        ax.set_ylabel('values')
        # legend
        legend=ax.legend(loc=('upper center'), shadow='true',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),ncol=3, fancybox=True)

        plt.style.use('dark_background')
        plt.savefig('result_dark.png')

        plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
        plt.savefig('result_white.png')
```

But it did not work properly. One of the images was correct. The second had a correct backgroundcolor, but the fontcolor of legend/labels did not change. I tried to separate the 2 images, the result was the same:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

def plot():
    #set pic size

    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    # set x data
    x = range(10)
    # set y data
    y1 = np.zeros(10)
    y2 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
    y3 = [3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
    #plot as errorbar
    ax.errorbar(x, y1, fmt='o', color='green', markersize=8, label='Normal')
    ax.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=0.2, fmt='o', color='orange', markersize=8, label='abw_up')
    ax.errorbar(x, y3, yerr=0.1, fmt='o', color='purple', markersize=8,label='abw_down')
    # limits
    ax.axhline(0.1*10, color='red', lw=2)
    ax.axhline(-0.1*10, color='red', lw=2)
    #set limit of y-Axis
    ax.set_ylim((-1.3,5.3))
    # Labels
    ax.set_xlabel('Messpunkte-Nr.\nMeasurement points number')
    ax.set_ylabel('Spezifikationsgrenze normiert\nnormed to specification')
    # legend
    legend=ax.legend(loc=('upper center'), shadow='true',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),ncol=3, fancybox=True)
    texts =legend.get_texts()
    texts[0].set_color('green')
    texts[1].set_color('orange')
    texts[2].set_color('purple')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=100)
plt.style.use('dark_background')
plot()
plt.savefig('result_dark.png')
plt.clf()
#plt.close()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=100)
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plot()
plt.savefig('result_white.png')
plt.clf()
#plt.close()
```

How should I fix my code to have 2 images with the same values, but different styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest structuring you code something like:

```
from matplotlib.style import context

def my_plot_function(ax, data, style):
    # do all of your plotting in here, should be fast as no computation
    pass

with context('dark'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    my_plot_function(ax, data, style)
    fig.savefig(...)

with context('fivethirtyeight'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    my_plot_function(ax, data, style)
    fig.savefig(...)
```

This is a design feature, not a bug. Almost all of the values controlled by rcparams are set at object creation time, not a draw time, because having what your figure will look like when you render it depend on global state is terrifying. This also allows you to use context managers for the rcparams, as shown above.  Calling `use` only over-rides the values that the style sheet explicitly sets (which is also a design feature so you can apply multiple styles a-la cascading style sheets).

Answer (score 1):

So your problem appears to be that you do a lot of plotting and then tell pylab you'd like your plots to have a particular style.  That instruction doesn't seem to be updating everything.  So instead, tell it you want to use a particular style.  Then plot.  Then clear everything.  Then plot again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot():
        #set pic size
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=100)
        ax = plt.subplot(111)
        # set x data
        x = range(10)
        # set y data
        y1 = np.zeros(10)
        y2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        y3 = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
        #plot as errorbar
        ax.errorbar(x, y1, fmt='o', color='green', markersize=8, label='Normal')
        ax.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=0.1, fmt='o', color='orange', markersize=8, label='abw_up')
        ax.errorbar(x, y3, yerr=0.1, fmt='o', color='purple', markersize=8,label='abw_down')
        # limits
        ax.axhline(0.1*10, color='red', lw=2)
        ax.axhline(-0.1*10, color='red', lw=2)
        #set limit of y-Axis
        ax.set_ylim((-1.3,1.3))
        # Labels
        ax.set_xlabel('points number')
        ax.set_ylabel('values')
        # legend
        legend=ax.legend(loc=('upper center'), shadow='true',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),ncol=3, fancybox=True)


plt.style.use('dark_background')
plot()
plt.savefig('result_dark.png')

plt.clf()
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plot()
plt.savefig('result_white.png')
```

Does this give what you want?  Here are the figures I got.

[image: result_dark]

[image: result_white]

Comment: I got the following output: "alloc: invalid block: 0556F7C0: 20 5"

Comment: I edited the second code:  I do not get the error "alloc" any more. But the code is not working properly...

Comment: Not sure what to suggest - the code snippet I provided seems to run fine on my computer and give output like I think you want...

Comment: These are the images what I am searching for. But if I am running your code I got an error message:  "alloc: invalid block: blahblah " I just don't know why.  My setup:  OS: Win7; Python3.4; Matplotlib: 1.4.2

Comment: Does it say what line it occurs in?

Comment: I'm running 2.7, so my best guess would be that there's some incompatibility there, but it might also be that something else you're doing is causing the problem (assuming you're running more than just the code I provided).

Comment: Just for testing: I copy-pasted your code. As a result, I got 2 images and the alloc error.  I've reported it on GitHub as well. Here you could see my images as well:  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4013